# Can Blend for Visual studio 2017 import psd file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Blend for Visual studio 2015 removed this feature.Can Blend for Visual studio 2017 import psd file now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed the Blend for Visual studio 2017,the answer is can not.